# Salesforce CLI tools do not work together with Git Bash on Windows

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, git, force-cli

I have a problem, when I try to use Salesforce CLI tools for DX, it works for when I type and execute them in standard windows "cmd" program but doesn't work when I run them from Git Bash terminal.

Looks like the problem is that it is installed into "Program Files" folder which contains spaces and git internal linux bash file and path system doesn't work well with spaces in the path.

I have asked [a similar question on SuperUser stackoverflow forum](https://superuser.com/questions/1331406/how-do-i-replace-path-environment-variable-items-to-double-quote-those-which-hav?noredirect=1#comment1989019_1331406), but nobody helped me to resolve this issue.

I tried to install CLI into separate folder without spaces, but it fails again, now because the folder itself has a space in it: "Salesforce CLI".

[image]

I am not sure if renaming the folder would help or quoting the folder path in the path system variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after renaming the folder into "C:\Tools\SalesforceCLI\bin" and modifying a path environment variable I was able to resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the content of the various sfdx.cmd files, I found that using `$LOCALAPPDATA/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx.cmd force:...` works in git bash under windows, because it bypasses the folder variables with spaces in it.

For those who don't want to reinstall sfdx, you can create a shortcut somewhere in the path.